# Python: Converting Astropy Table into an Array (Using Numpy?) for Plotting (on matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, astropy

I have an Astropy Table as such:

```
         a           b    c 
------------------- ---- ---
-0.6096212422044334  2.0 3.0
-1.2192424844088667 10.0 3.0
   -5.4865911798399  9.0 3.0
```

I want to turn this table back into an array for plotting purposes. This is what I tried:

```
d=Table(t)
x=np.array(d)
print(x)
```

This is what I get back (which I believe is a tuple):

```
[(-0.60962124,  2., 3.) (-1.21924248, 10., 3.) (-5.48659118,  9., 3.)]
```

When I ask for 'np.shape(x)' I get (3,) which is why I believe it is a tuple. I need the shape to be (3,3) so I can call out individual elements and plot this information.

Thank you, Q

Comment: is this a csv file ? If it is a simple csv file, you can upload it into python as a dataframe and then plot individual columns. Why do you need ```Table``` command?

Comment: This was originally a .txt file. I converted it to a table using Astropy so I could edit certain things like add/delete rows based on certain criteria (e.g. delete row if column 2 value is less than 10). I need to use the Table function so I can make those changes. Maybe I could upload the updated Table as a new .txt file and then bring it back into Python as an array?

Answer (score 2):

This is a numpy [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html) in which the "elements" of the array are not single float values, but rather *triplets* (in this case) of floats. It does this in part because in the general case that all columns are not the same data type, the original format of the data is still preserved (3 columns and 3 (possibly) heterogeneous rows). This is why the shape is `(3,)`.

In this case you can safely convert to a `(3, 3)` homogenous array because all the columns have a floating point data type. There are a few different ways to do this but one of the easiest and safest is the [`structured_to_unstructured`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured) utility function.

**Update:** Now that at I'm at my computer, here's a concrete example based on yours:

```
>>> f = io.BytesIO(b"""\ 
...          a           b    c  
... ------------------- ---- --- 
... -0.6096212422044334  2.0 3.0 
... -1.2192424844088667 10.0 3.0 
...    -5.4865911798399  9.0 3.0 
... """)                                                                                       
>>> t = Table.read(f, format='ascii.fixed_width_two_line')                                     
>>> t                                                                                          
<Table length=3>
         a             b       c   
      float64       float64 float64
------------------- ------- -------
-0.6096212422044334     2.0     3.0
-1.2192424844088667    10.0     3.0
   -5.4865911798399     9.0     3.0
>>> t.as_array()                                                                               
array([(-0.60962124,  2., 3.), (-1.21924248, 10., 3.),
       (-5.48659118,  9., 3.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
>>> a = np.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured(t.as_array())                           
>>> a                                                                                          
array([[-0.60962124,  2.        ,  3.        ],
       [-1.21924248, 10.        ,  3.        ],
       [-5.48659118,  9.        ,  3.        ]])
>>> a.shape                                                                                    
(3, 3)
```